# although true entity naming i get ( mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property exception)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

although true entity naming i get mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property
regarding to [this](http://Caused%20by:%20org.hibernate.AnnotationException:%20mappedBy%20reference%20an%20unknown%20target%20entity%20property%202) and [this](http://Caused%20by:%20org.hibernate.AnnotationException:%20mappedBy%20reference%20an%20unknown%20target%20entity%20property:%202) the solution for mappedby exception is to naming the entity correctly i did that but i still getting the exception

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTEST")
public class Contest extends eg.com.etisalat.base.entity.BaseEntity implements
    Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CONTEST_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_CONTEST_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CONTEST_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID")
private long contestId;

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH }
,mappedBy="contest")
private List<Challenge> challenges;
//attributes
//getters &setters
}
```

and this is the ohter entity which has a many to one relation with contest entity

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CHALLENGE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_Challenge_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CHALLENGE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "CHALLENGE_ID")
private long Id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Contest.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTEST_ID")
private Contest conestId;
//attributes
//getters &setters
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In `Challenge` entity, the field should be `private Contest contest;` with a matching getter and setter - `getContest()` and `setContest()`. Does it work with this combination? If not, please post the whole exception.

Comment: yes it works correctly without throwing exception after renaming the proprety to contest and create set and get for it thanks alot @PredragMaric   for your time :)

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer since it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Challenge` entity, the field should be `private Contest contest;` with a matching getter and setter - `getContest()` and `setContest()`.